# Теорема о пробном частном C++

Tags: c++, длинная-арифметика

Помогите разобраться в теореме Дональда Кнута: теорема о пробном частном.

Я использую эту теорему для деления больших чисел и вычисления остатка при делении, но проблема в том, что я пересмотрел кучу сайтов, кодов, даже в его книгу смотрел чтобы понять как это все работает. И все без успешно. Не помогали даже Ctrl+C и  Ctrl+V (пытался скопировать, чтобы пошагово разобраться алгоритм)

Пожалуйста, кто разбирается объясните простым языком как работает эта теорема.

Буду очень благодарен если напишите псевдокод и буду рад если закрепите все ссылочкой на простую и понятную реализацию этого алгоритма в принципе на любом языке.

Comment: По сути это человеческое деление в столбик. Что конкретно вам не понятно? Скажите - подскажем:)

Comment: Вот этот человек неплохо рассказывает про длинную арифметику (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cavS5rqZdDs), в том числе про деление. Говорят, это лучшее на русскоязычном Youtube пособие по длинной арифметике. Правда, неполное, человек куда-то слился.

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev вообще все. Начиная с 1 пункта. Я понял что надо найти d = Base / (цифру + 1) а что за цифра последняя или первая, делителя или делимого. Везде по разному видел. Потом надо добавить 1 разряд к делимогу и я ну вроде понял что в конец. Потом цикл не очень понятен как работает. Я думаю вы сможете помочь если объясните своими простыми словами. Типа 1) добавить разряд к делимогу в конец числа. d = Base / (конец делителя + 1) далее умножаем. И псевдокод можно прикрепить. И я думаю я пойму.

Answer (score 3):

Создадим для начала класс:

```
class BigInt {
    public:
    // к этим членам можно закрыть доступ
    ulong Size, SizeMax;    // Size – текущая длина
    // SizeMax – максимальная длина
    short *Coef;    // Массив коэффициентов

    // в этом случае здесь также должны быть описаны дружественные функции
    // операций над большими числами, которые будут разобраны ниже. 
    BigInt ();
    BigInt (ulong);
    BigInt (const BigInt&); 
    virtual ~BigInt ();
    void zero ();   // Обнулить число
    void update ();
    BigInt& operator = (const BigInt&);
    operator long ();   // Оператор преобразования BigInt к типу long
};
```

Создадим конструкторы и деструктор объектов класса:

```
BigInt::BigInt () {
    SizeMax = Size = 0; // Объявление вида BigInt A;
    Coef = NULL;    // Создается полностью пустое число
}

BigInt::BigInt (ulong MaxLen) {
    Coef = new short [MaxLen]; //Объявление вида BigInt A(10); 
    SizeMax = MaxLen;   // Выделяет память под MaxLen цифр Size = 0;
}

BigInt::BigInt (const BigInt &A) { // Конструктор копирования
    SizeMax = A.SizeMax;    // Создает B, равное A 
    Size = A.Size;
    Coef = new short [SizeMax];
    for (ulong i=0; i<SizeMax; i++) Coef [i] = A.Coef [i];
}

BigInt::~BigInt () {    // Деструктор (Освобождает память) 
    delete Coef;
}
```

Создадим операцию обнуления числа:

```
void BigInt::zero () {  // A.zero () – обнулить число
    for (ulong i=0; i<SizeMax; i++) Coef [i] = 0; Size = 1;
}
```

Создадим оператор вычисления значения числа в «обычном виде» (полезен при отладке, когда BASE=10 и числа небольшие):

```
BigInt::operator long () {
    long tmp = 0;   // при вычислениях может произойти переполнение
    for (ushort i=0; i<Size; i++) tmp += Coef [i] * (long) pow ( BASE, (real) i ); return tmp;
}
```

Создадим оператор присваивания:

```
inline BigInt& BigInt::operator = (const BigInt &A) { const short *a = A.Coef;
    if (this == &A) return *this;   // Если присваивание вида A=A, выйти
    if ( SizeMax < A.Size ) {   // Если размера не хватает,
        // переинициализация
        if (Coef) delete Coef;
        Coef = new short [A.Size]; SizeMax = Size = A.Size;
    } else Size = A.Size;

    for (ulong l=0; l<Size; l++) Coef [l] = a [l];
    return *this;
}
```

Учтены, в том числе, особые случаи применения оператора:

1. Случай A = A;
2. Случай необходимости выделения дополнительной памяти под коэффициенты, если размеры операндов не совпадают;
3. Случай A = B = C (интерпретируется как A = ( B = C ) ).

Создадим оператор вывода на печать:

```
#define BASE_DIG 4  // Полагаем, что BASE = 10000

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const BigInt& A) {   // Перегрузка оператора << long j, Digit=0;
    short Pow, Dec, Coef;

    os << A.Coef[A.Size-1];
    for (long i=A.Size-2; i>=0; i--) {  // Цикл вывода коэффициентов
    Pow = BASE/10;
    Coef = A.Coef[i];
        for (j=0; j<BASE_DIG; j++) {    // Цикл, выводящий каждый коэффициент
            Dec = Coef/Pow; Coef -= Dec*Pow;
            Pow /= 10;  // Очередная цифра получается делением
            os << Dec;  // коэффициента на 10j 
            Digit++;
            // Каждые 1000 цифр сопровождаются переходом строки
            if (Digit%1000==0) os << "\n\n";
            else if (Digit%50==0) os << "\t: " << Digit << "\n";
        }
    }
    return os;
}
```

Создадим оператор сложения:

```
// Вычисление C = A+B, работает вызов вида Add (A, B, A).
// Максимальный размер C должен быть достаточен для хранения суммы
void Add(const BigInt &A, const BigInt &B, BigInt &C) { ulong i;
    long temp;  // temp здесь и далее играет роль “временной” цифры,
    // до выполнения переноса. Возможно, temp > BASE.

    // Здесь и в следующих примерах
    // для быстрого доступа к коэффициентам
    // объявляются временные указатели a, b, c. 
    const short *a=A.Coef, *b=B.Coef; 
    short *c=C.Coef;

    carry = 0;  // перенос в следующий разряд

    // Добиваемся B.Size ≤ A.Size. 
    if ( A.Size < B.Size ) {
        Add(B,A,C);
        return;
    }
    // Теперь B.Size ≤ A.Size. Складываем два числа, i -номер текущей цифры
    for (i=0; i<B.Size; i++) {
        temp = a[i] + b[i] + carry;
        if (temp >= BASE) { 
            // Переполнение. Перенести единицу. 
            c[i] = temp - BASE; carry = 1; }

        else {
            c[i] = temp;    carry = 0;
        }
    } 

    // Меньшее число кончилось
    for (; i < A.Size; i++) { 
        temp = a[i] + carry; 
        if (temp >= BASE) {
            c[i] = temp - BASE;     carry = 1;  } 
        else { 
            c[i] = temp;    
            carry = 0;  }
    }

    // Если остался перенос – добавить его в дополнительный разряд
    if (carry) { 
        c[i] = carry;   
        C.Size = A.Size+1; } 
    else C.Size = A.Size;
}
```

Создадим оператор вычитания:

```
// C = A-B, должно быть A.Size >= B.Size. Работает вызов Sub(A, B, A).
// Если длины равны, но A<B: возвращается -1, результат будет дополнением. 
int Sub (const BigInt& A, const BigInt& B, BigInt& C) {
    const short *a=A.Coef, *b=B.Coef; short *c=C.Coef;
    ulong i;
    long temp, carry=0;
    if ( A.Size < B.Size ) error ("BigSub: size error");

    for (i=0; i<B.Size; i++) {
        temp = a[i] - b[i] + carry; 
        if (temp < 0) {
            c[i] = temp + BASE; carry = -1; } 
        else { c[i] = temp; carry = 0; }
    }
    for (; i<A.Size; i++) { 
        temp = a[i] + carry; 
        if (temp < 0) {
            c[i] = temp + BASE; carry = -1;  
        }
        else {
            c[i] = temp; carry = 0;
        }
    }    

    // Размер результата может быть гораздо меньше, чем у исходного числа
    // Устанавливаем его по первому положительному разряду
    i = A.Size-1;
    while ( (i>0) && (c[i]==0) ) i--; 
    C.Size = i+1;
    return carry;
}
```

Создадим упрощенный оператор умножения:

```
// C = A * B, работает вызов Smul (A, B, A).
void SMul (const BigInt &A, const short B, BigInt &C) { 
    ulong i, temp;
    const short *a=A.Coef; 
    short *c=C.Coef, carry=0; 
    for (i=0; i<A.Size;i++) {
        temp = a[i]*B + carry; carry = temp / BASE;
        c[i] = temp - carry*BASE;   // с[i] = temp % BASE ( Так очень медленно ! )
    }
    if (carry) {
        // Число удлинилось за счет переноса нового разряда
        c[i] = carry; C.Size = A.Size+1;
    }
    else C.Size = A.Size;
}
```

Создадим оператор умножения общего вида:

```
// C = A * B, работает вызов Mul (A, B, A)
void Mul (const BigInt &A, const BigInt &B, BigInt &C) { 
    ulong i, j;
    const short *a=A.Coef, *b=B.Coef; 
    short *c=C.Coef;
    ulong temp, carry;

    // Обнулить необходимую для работы часть C 
    for ( i=0; i <= A.Size + B.Size; i++ ) c[i]=0;
    // Выполнение основного цикла умножения
    for ( i = 0; i < A.Size; i++) { 
        carry = 0;
        // вычисление временного результата с одновременным прибавлением
        // его к c[i+j] (делаются переносы) 
        for (j = 0; j < B.Size; j++) {
            temp = a[i] * b[j] + c[i+j] + carry; 
            carry = temp / BASE;
            c[i+j] = temp - carry*BASE;
            }
            c[i+j] = carry;
        }
        // Установить размер по первой ненулевой цифре
        i = A.Size + B.Size - 1; 
        if ( c[i] == 0 ) i--; 
        C.Size = i+1;
}
```

Создадим упрощенный оператор деления:

```
// Частное Q = A/B. Остаток R = A%B. A, Q – длинные целые. B, R – короткие целые. 
void SDiv(const BigInt &A, const short B, BigInt &Q, short &R) {
    short r=0, *q=Q.Coef; 
    const short *a=A.Coef; 
    long i, temp;

    for ( i=A.Size-1; i>=0; i--) {  
        // идти по A, начиная от старшего разряда
        temp = r*BASE + a[i];   // r – остаток от предыдущего деления
                                // вначале r=0, temp – текущая цифра A с
                                // учетом перенесенного остатка

        q[i] = temp / B;    // i-я цифра частного
        r = temp - q[i]*B;  // остаток примет участие в вычислении
                            // следующей цифры частного
        }
    R = r;
    // Размер частного меньше, либо равен размера делимого
    i = A.Size-1;
    while ( (i>0) && (q[i]==0) ) i--; 
    Q.Size = i+1;
}
```

И финально, применив теорему Дональда Кнута реализуем общий оператор деления:

```
// Частное Q = A/B. Остаток R = A%B.
// Все операнды – длинные целые.

void Div (const BigInt &A, BigInt &B, BigInt &Q, BigInt &R) {

    // Вырожденный случай 1. Делитель больше делимого. 
    if ( A.Size < B.Size ) {
        Q.zero();
        R=A;
        return;
    }

    // Вырожденный случай 2. Делитель – короткое целое. 
    if ( B.Size == 1) {
        SDiv ( A, B.Coef[0], Q, R.Coef[0]);
        R.Size = 1; 
        return;
    }
    // Создать временный массив U, равный A
    // Максимальный размер U на цифру больше A, с учетом
    // возможного удлинения A при нормализации
    BigInt U(A.Size+1); 
    U = A; 
    U.Coef[A.Size]=0;
    // Указатели для быстрого доступа
    short *b=B.Coef, *u=U.Coef, *q=Q.Coef;

    long n=B.Size, m=U.Size-B.Size; 
    long uJ, vJ, i;
    long temp1, temp2, temp;
    short scale;    // коэффициент нормализации
    short qProbe, r;    // догадка для частного и соответствующий остаток
    short borrow, carry;    // переносы

    // Нормализация
    scale = BASE / ( b[n-1] + 1 ); 
    if (scale > 1) {
        SMul (U, scale, U);
        SMul (B, scale, B);
    }
    // Главный цикл шагов деления.
    // Каждая итерация дает очередную цифру частного.
    // vJ - текущий сдвиг B относительно U, используемый при вычитании,
    // по совместительству - индекс очередной цифры частного.
    // uJ – индекс текущей цифры U

    for (vJ = m, uJ=n+vJ; vJ>=0; --vJ, --uJ) {
        qProbe = (u[uJ]*BASE + u[uJ-1]) / b[n-1];
        r = (u[uJ]*BASE + u[uJ-1]) % b[n-1];

        // Пока не будут выполнены необходимые условия, уменьшать частное. 
        while ( r < BASE) {
            temp2 = b[n-2]*qProbe; temp1 = r*BASE + u[uJ-2];
            if ( (temp2 > temp1) || (qProbe==BASE) ) {
                // условия не выполнены, уменьшить qProbe
                // и досчитать новый остаток
                --qProbe;
                r += b[n-1];
            } else break;
        }
        // Теперь qProbe - правильное частное или на единицу больше q
        // Вычесть делитель B, умноженный на qProbe из делимого U,
        // начиная с позиции vJ+i 
        carry = 0; 
        borrow = 0; 
        short *uShift = u + vJ;
        // цикл по цифрам B 
        for (i=0; i<n;i++) {
            // получить в temp цифру произведения B*qProbe 
            temp1 = b[i]*qProbe + carry;
            carry = temp1 / BASE; temp1 -= carry*BASE;
            // Сразу же вычесть из U
            temp2 = uShift[i] - temp1 + borrow; 
            if (temp2 < 0) {
                uShift[i] = temp2 + BASE; 
                borrow = -1;             
            } else {
                uShift[i] = temp2; 
                borrow = 0;
            }
        }

        // Возможно, умноженое на qProbe число B удлинилось.
        // Если это так, то после умножения остался
        // неиспользованный перенос carry. Вычесть и его тоже. 
        temp2 = uShift[i] - carry + borrow;
        if (temp2 < 0) {
            uShift[i] = temp2 + BASE; 
            borrow = -1;         
        } else {
            uShift[i] = temp2; 
            borrow = 0;
        }

        // Прошло ли вычитание нормально ?
        if (borrow == 0) {  
            // Да, частное угадано правильно
            q[vJ] = qProbe;
        } 
        else {  
            // Нет, последний перенос при вычитании borrow = -1,
            // значит, qProbe на единицу больше истинного частного
            q[vJ] = qProbe-1;
            // добавить одно, вычтенное сверх необходимого B к U carry = 0;
            for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
                temp = uShift[i] + b[i] + carry; 
                if (temp >= BASE) {
                    uShift[i] = temp - BASE; 
                    carry = 1;

                } else {
                    uShift[i] = temp; 
                    carry = 0;
                }
            }

            uShift[i] = uShift[i] + carry - BASE;
        }

        // Обновим размер U, который после вычитания мог уменьшиться
        i = U.Size-1;
        while ( (i>0) && (u[i]==0) ) i--;
        U.Size = i+1;
    }
    // Деление завершено !

    // Размер частного равен m+1, но, возможно, первая цифра - ноль. 
    while ( (m>0) && (q[m]==0) ) m--;
    Q.Size = m+1;

    // Если происходило домножение на нормализующий множитель –
    // разделить на него. То, что осталось от U – остаток. 
    if (scale > 1) {
        short junk; // почему-то остаток junk всегда будет равен нулю… 
        SDiv ( B, scale, B, junk);
        SDiv ( U, scale, R, junk);
    } else R=U;
}
```

Пример словами, как работает теорема.

Дано:

> Делимое - 38674
>
> Делитель - 673
>
> СС - 10

*Первая итерация:*

> Длинна делителя - 3.
>
> Берем первые 3 цифры числа - 386.
>
> 386 < 673, значит берем 3867.

*Вторая итерация:*

> Делимое - 3867
>
> Делитель - 673
>
> Q.PROB = (3 * 10 + 8) / 6 = 6,....
>
> 6 * 673 = 4038, значит пробуем (Q.PROB - 1)
>
> 5 * 673 = 3365.
>
> Остаток: 502.

*Третья итерация:*

> Делимое - 5024
>
> Делитель - 673
>
> Q.PROB = (5 * 10 + 0) / 6 = 8,....
>
> 8 * 673 = 5384, значит пробуем (Q.PROB - 1)
>
> 7 * 673 = 4711.
>
> Остаток:  313.

*Больше цифр в делимом нет, значит закончили деление.*

Comment: [Вероятный источник](https://kspt.icc.spbstu.ru/media/files/2012/course/comp-algebra/CAS_L04.pdf) (вторая ссылка в гугле по запросу «теорема о пробном частном»).

Comment: Нет это конечно круто, но я все вот это уже переписывал. Но не кажеться ли вам, что код просто огромен. И я могу просто переписать да, но мне надо понятб как это делается. Что за borrow и тд.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков так абсолютно все же комментарии есть. Или вам не понятно, что это за сдвиг?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков я поэтому и спрашивал, что конкретно не понятно. Представьте, что это ручное деление в столбик. Где затык?

Comment: Ну вот я правильно рассуждаю? Сначала находим `d = base / (старший разряд делителя + 1)` умножаем делимое и делитель на это d и добавляем разряд к делимому. То есть 123 станет 1230 или в массиве [3,2,1] станет [3,2,1,0]. Далее я не знаю что делать. в комментариях под моим вопросом кто-то ссылку на видео указал и на нем автор делает по другому немножно.

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev можете пожалуйста объяснить на примере. Взять например два числа 123 и 45 в десятичной системе счисления. И объяснить как делить числа по этому алгоритму.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков привел вам пример

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev я тут как раз понял, как работает алгоритм в видео, которое в комментарии к ответу скидывали. И вариант, который вы привели намного проще. Вы уверены, что ваш алгоритм всегда правильно работает. Просто меня смущает тот факт, что ваш алгоритм намного легче в реализации и быстрее в работе. Тк в варианте автора например нужно делить 3 разряда на 2 разряда. А для этого свой алгоритм над, которым я еще часа 2 сижу. Ладно попробую протестировать

Comment: @ПавелЕриков не забывайте только, что если значение старшей цифры делителя <СС/2, то вам надо и делимое и делитель домножать на коэффициент. И если быть более точным, то у вас был вопрос к теореме. Теорема работает при определенных условия (поэтому и происходит домножение, если не попадает под условие). А алгоритмов деления больших чисел очень много, поэтому реализации и отличаются. В первую очередь по сложности алгоритмов

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev а почему вы в примере не домножили и получили правильный ответ?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Потому что 6 >= 10/2

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev ааа делителя же, да не увидел.